# Wrap local macro in double quotes that will be visible to esttab's cells() option

Tags: stata

I am trying to lazily create a table of means and standard errors for a longish list of variables. It seems that the `estout` package from SSC and `tabstat` are the best tools, but I can't get the local macros to work properly to specify `esttab`'s `cells()` option.

```
sysuse auto, clear

* build macro for `cells()` option
local i = 1
foreach v of varlist price weight displacement {
    local cells "`cells'" " `v'"
    if (`i' == 1) local cells "`cells'(fmt(%9.3gc))"
    local ++i
}

* properly built
display "`cells'"

* but does not work with `esttab`
estpost tabstat price weight displacement, statistics(mean semean)
esttab ., cells("`cells'")
```

This yields an "empty" table.

```
. esttab ., cells("`cells'")

-------------------------
                      (1)

                        b
-------------------------
-------------------------
N                      74
-------------------------
```

It seems that `cells()` needs to see double quotes, but my attempts to add them with single and double quotes at any point in the process. Is there a way to make this approach work? I would like to avoid manually generating the `cells()` argument.

```
* The following approach does work.
esttab ., cells("price(fmt(%9.3gc)) weight displacement")
```

This yields the correct table.

```
. esttab ., cells("price(fmt(%9.3gc)) weight displacement")

---------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                          

                    price       weight displacement
---------------------------------------------------
mean                6,165        3,019          197
semean                343         90.3         10.7
---------------------------------------------------
N                      74                          
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nick has already given a solution to the problem. He claims only stylistic changes were made, but I suspect more.

The double quotes originally used by the poster introduce an additional word in the definition of `local cells`. That is clear when we count the words contained in the local macro using the *extended macro function* `: word count`. @Richard works with three variables, but we count four words. Carefull inspection shows that the additional, *surprise word*, is `""`, introduced in the loop its first time around.

In this case, using `display` to check the contents of the local is misleading, because the command will simply do away with `""`. As a result, we see on screen "three" words. Displaying each word (one by one), more clearly shows that the first one is a blank.

What this means is you are coding something like:

```
esttab ., cells(""" price weight displacement")
```

when you really mean

```
esttab ., cells("price weight displacement")
```

Below I post some code consistent with this hypothesis. To simplify exposition, I have stripped away unnecessary complications from the original code.

```
sysuse auto, clear

// build macro
local i = 1
foreach v of varlist price weight displacement {
    local cells "`cells'" " `v'"
    *local cells `cells' `v'
}

// check contents of macro cells
local wc : word count "`cells'"   
display `wc'

forvalues i = 1/4 {
    local w`i' : word `i' of "`cells'" 
    display "`w`i''"
}

// display a test
local test "" " price" " weight" " displacement"
local wct : word count "`test'"
display `wct' // four words also

// more displays
display "`cells'" 
display """ price weight displacement" // same display result 

// tables

// post
quietly estpost tabstat price weight displacement, statistics(mean semean)

// original with error
esttab ., cells("`cells'")

// original with error after dereferencing the local macro cells
esttab ., cells(""" price weight displacement")
```

Nick's solution, that doesn't use double quotes, solves the problem.

Comment: Forensic Stata! Thanks, Roberto! So it isn't the double quotes, *per se*, just the empty word they create on the first loop. Not to mention that the space in double quotes is completely unnecessary. Thanks for the thorough lesson. *Very* helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One clue might be that the `assert` is not passing:

```
sysuse auto, clear

* build macro for `cells()` option
local i = 1
foreach v of varlist price weight displacement {
    local cells "`cells'" " `v'"
    if (`i' == 1) local cells "`cells'(fmt(%9.3gc))"
    local ++i
}

* properly built
display "`cells'"

* but does not work with `esttab`
estpost tabstat price weight displacement, statistics(mean semean)

display "`cells'"
esttab ., cells("`cells'")

local cells2 price(fmt(%9.3gc)) weight displacement
esttab ., cells("`cells2'")

assert "`cells'" == "`cells2'"

esttab ., cells(price(fmt(%9.3gc)) weight displacement)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `assert`. I agree my code doesn't work. :) Nick's clean-up fixes my problem (why, I'm still not sure). Thanks for the help.

Comment: I comment on the why in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Stata 13.1 and updated `estout` from SSC. My changes from your code were intended just as stylistic, but see an answer from @Roberto Ferrer.

I did get an error with an older version lurking on my machine, so updating  appears to be at least part of the solution.

```
sysuse auto, clear

* build macro for `cells()` option
local i = 1
foreach v of varlist price weight displacement {
    local cells `cells' `v'
    if (`i' == 1) local cells `cells'(fmt(%9.3gc))
    local ++i
}

* properly built
display "`cells'"

estpost tabstat price weight displacement, statistics(mean semean)
esttab ., cells("`cells'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prod -- I should have added that I'm on a fully updated Stata 11.2. But your changes fixed the problem. There is something wrong with my double quote usage in my original code. Thanks for the help.